# test if python object is valid

Tags: python, c, cython

I am wrapping c library for Python using Cython.
I have pointers to callable Python objects in my C code to call them back later from C code.
How to ensure a callback is not garbage collected or deleted if I only have address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `__Pyx_INCREF(obj)` the object you're holding -- this ensures it won't go away!  **Do** remember to `__Pyx_DECREF(obj)` once you're done with it -- and, see https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/refcounting for details!-)

Comment: I know how to prevent gc collection. I usually put it in list or dict(on Python or cython side), question is how to test validity given an address.

Comment: @AlexV., the answer is, **no** way.  If you chose not to hold on to the object it could have been freed so the memory at that address might now be garbage (no way to ensure it **is** garbage) or part of some other completely unrelated object.  If you care, **hold on** to the object -- memory is fungible and given nothing but an address there isn't, nor ever will be!, a way to check with certainty "this is the address of a PyObj that somebody else has kindly kept alive for me as I couldn't be bothered"!-)